# How to make multilevel menu in php, mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, menu, cascade

I want to make a multilevel menu in php, but it doesn't work. is there anyone who knows why below code can't generate the first html code in the if close?

```
 <?php
include "db.php";
if(isset($_POST["category"])){
$category_query="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE part='Product' ";
$run_query=mysqli_query($con,$category_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
        $cat_id=$row["cat_id"];
        $cat_name=$row["cat_name"];
        for ($i=0; $i<count($cat_id); $i++) {
            $category_query2="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id='$cat_id[$i]' ";
            $run_query2=mysqli_query($con,$category_query2);
            $j=0;
            if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query2)>0){
                $j++;
                echo "
                    <li><a class='dropdown-button d' href='#' data-activates='dropdown2' data-hover=\"hover\" data-alignment=\"left\">$cat_name</a></li>
                    ";

            } else {
                echo "
                    <li><a herf='2#'>$cat_name</a></li>
                 ";
            }

        }

    }

}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the output now? How is the data structured? And btw: There is a typo in the else-part: "herf" instead of "href"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code should be change like this.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query2)>0){`
    $j++;
    echo "HTML code 'attribute' ".$cat_name."HTML code";`
 } else {`
    echo "HTML code".$cat_name."HTML code";`
 }
```